# Text Field boundaries are not showing properly

Tags: ios, objective-c

As I have used padding, corner radius as well as text top alignment. What mistake I did so the text fields are not showing properly in simulator when I run the app in simulator 5s or less.

[Simulator ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NQKt.png)

[Code I did ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2g1OH.png)

Comment: click `command + 1` when simulator is open, it should look properly, it is because you simulator is downsized.

Comment: @Zaid Pathan, are you sure sir will it work fine when I'll try in iphone instead of its result in simulator . ...

Comment: yes, it should be working, have you tested as I described?

Comment: @Zaid Pathan yes sir the screen siZe increases, it works. So, its a problem with simulator siZe. Thanks :)